# Calculating the Interior of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $$X=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2+y^2+z^2\leq4 \space,\space x>1 \} $$

Find $\mathring{X}$ (the interior of the given set, $X$).

I did the following:

Given $X=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3} \vert x^2+y^2+z^2\leq4 \space,\space x>1 \} $, the set can be re-written as $$X=f^{-1}(-\infty,4]\cap g^{-1}(1,\infty)$$
where $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $g(x,y,z)=x$ are continuous functions. The set is neither open nor closed. We now assume that $$\mathring{X}=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2+y^2+z^2<4 \space,\space x>1 \}$$
Then $$\mathring{X}=f^{-1}(-\infty,4)\cap g^{-1}(1,\infty)$$
Which, as a finite intersection of open pre-images of continuous functions, is open.
Therefore $$\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2+y^2+z^2<4 \space,\space x>1 \}\subseteq\mathring{X}\subseteq X$$

From here what I suppose I need to do is prove that the points $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ (maybe $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq4$?) and $x\leq1$ are not in the interior. So I can take an open ball around any such point $(a,b,c)$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=4$ and prove that there are points in the ball outside of our set $X$.
Or maybe there's another way of doing this? Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let$$Y=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2<4\wedge x>1\}.$$You have proved that $Y$ is an open set and it is clear that $Y\subset X$. So, $Y\subset\mathring X$. In order to prove that they're equal, you have to prove that if $(x,y,z)\in X\setminus Y$, then $(x,y,z)\notin\mathring X$. So, take $(x,y,z)\in X\setminus Y$. This means that $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and that $x>1$. Take any ball centered at $(x,y,z)$ and any $r>0$ and consider the point $\left(x,y,z+\frac r2\right)$. Then $\left(x,y,z+\frac r2\right)\in B_r\bigl((x,y,z)\bigr)$, but $\left(x,y,z+\frac r2\right)\notin X$. Since this happens for every $r>0$, $(x,y,z)\notin\mathring X$.